# urlloader event if url is not found

Tags: flash-cs5

I am using urlloader to send an xml document to an asp page, which then returns a status of correct via response.write "response=success"

How do I trap the error of the url not being found?

I have the following event listeners added

```
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onRequestComplete, false, 0, true);
ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onRequestFailure, false, 0, true);
ldr.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityViolation, false, 0, true);
```

But what should I use if the url does not exist?

The error I get is :

Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
    at Error$/throwError()
    at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
    at flash.net::URLVariables()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Thanks for any help

The full code snippet is

```
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://server1/capita/writeXMLtoDB.asp");
req.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;     
var sendVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
sendVariables.xmlDataToSend = xmlData.toXMLString();
req.data = sendVariables;
ldr = new URLLoader();
ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onRequestComplete, false, 0, true);
ldr.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onRequestFailure, false, 0, true);
ldr.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecurityViolation, false, 0, true);
ldr.load(req);
```

Comment: post the code snippet in which you are creating a urlrequest and calling urluploader.load()

Comment: I have amended the original question, thanks

Comment: I think URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES has to be URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT if you are dealing with XML